# Gamma correction with Upstart and a script

Tags: brightness, upstart

I've written an Upstart job to automatically change display gamma according to change in display brightness:

```
start on (backlight-device-changed)
exec /usr/bin/gammach
```

And this is "gammach":

```
#! /bin/bash
Br=`cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/actual_brightness` # Display brightness
Gm=.$((((Br+76)%100)))                      # Corrected gamma according to brightness
xrandr --output LVDS --gamma $Gm:$Gm:$Gm
```

But every time i change brightness i receive this error in the log file:

```
Can't open display
```

I have tried xgamma, but received a similar error.
Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer.
Apparently it was with permission and authorization to access Xserver and stuff like that.
The `xgamma` version of my script that works like a charm is:

```
#! /bin/bash
export XAUTHORITY=/home/<username>/.Xauthority  # This give permission to access Xserver
Br=`cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/actual_brightness` # Display brightness
Gm=.$((((Br+76)%100)))                      # Corrected gamma according to brightness
xgamma -d :0 -gamma $Gm
```

Answer (score 0):

The program you use needs to access the X server, and does not know which X display it should use.

In most cases, you can work around this by setting a fixed display name `:0.0`, which is normally the name of the first display, and the one if only one is running.

For example, at the start of your script, you can use:

`export DISPLAY=:0.0`

In general, you could have **multiple displays**, like if you run multiple X servers on multiple consoles, or **nested** X servers like Xnest, or Xvnc.

Also, you can have **one X server** running only, which has a **different** display name than `:0.0`, like `:10.0`

In these cases, you need to find a way to specify to your script which DISPLAY to use.

To get some useful output in your log, you could add:

`pgrep -fa /usr/bin/X`

to show whether one or more X servers are actually running at the time the upstart job is run. The command lines may also show the displays they run on.
And

`echo DISPLAY: "\"$DISPLAY\""`

to write the DISPLAY variable to the log.

Comment: But my script works fine in a terminal. Sorry if i can't see the picture.

Comment: In the termainal, when running X, there is the environment variable `DISPLAY` set to the display you are using: try `echo $DISPLAY` in a terminal under X. Then try the same on a text console - there will be no DISPLAY variable, and the `xrandr` command will behave like in the upstart job. By the way: are you sure the X server is already running when the script is run?

Comment: @user273010 Try adding the two lines from my edit to the top of your script, that should give some hints.

Comment: Yea i am sure. I am in normal unity environment. And I've tried different values in -display option in xgamma command and also put the "LVDS" in my script for the same reason. Isn't that enough?

Comment: The command `xrandr` does not know much about the configuration - it needs to talk to the `RandR` extension of your X server.

Comment: 1088 /usr/bin/X -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
DISPLAY: ""
Can't open display

Comment: Oh! I confess. I'm so much newbie! I think i should learn more about environment variables and processes that use them. Thank you for your FAST responses!

Comment: No problem, I remember solving the same question some years ago... You should accept the answer (with the tick mark) if it solved your problem (and upvote if you like).

Comment: Yea sure i will.